# How to use cache writer and cache loader in case of Ehcache server

Tags: ehcache

I have used **cache-as-sor** usage pattern of **Ehcache** in my web application. now i want to use ehcahe as separate application so i have used **cache server**. so how to use cache writer and cache loader in case of ehcache server.

In short i want to use method like **cache.getWithLoader()** and **cache.putWithWriter()**.

Answer (score 1):

As the cache server does not expose these methods, you may be able to handle this by [configuring Ehcache in the cache server](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.6/modules/cache-server#installation) to use [decorated caches](http://ehcache.org/documentation/2.6/apis/cache-decorators) that would transform standard `get` and `put` into calling into `getWithLoader` and `putWithWriter` instead.